# How to convert Angular code to ES5

Tags: angular

```
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart",
    (event, current, previous, rejection) => {
      if (/#\//.test($window.location.hash)) {
        $location.path($window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
      }
});
```

how to convert to ES5?

I want to remove => code because uglify can not work with it ...

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart",
   function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
    if (/#\//.test($window.location.hash)) {
      $location.path($window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
    }
 });
```

Comment: Some explanation please?

Comment: @zgoda "function() {}" and "() => { }" is nearly the same, except the second one keeps this context and its ES6.

Comment: Your answer was marked as "low quality" by SO because it lacks any explanation of provided code.